# Boost phoenix member function operator fails to compile if function has overload

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I want to use Boost phoenix member function operator for the class function that has overloads, like [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/operator.html).

The following example fails:

```
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/operator.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::phoenix::placeholders;

struct A
{
    int m_id = 1;
    int func() const { return 1; }
    void func(int id) { m_id = id; }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A;
    auto retVal = (arg1->*&A::func)()(a);

    return 0;
}
```

With error:

```
    In function 'int main()': 17:21: error: no match for 'operator->*'
(operand types are 'const type {aka const
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::
tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> 
>}' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>') 17:21: note: candidate is: In
 file included from /usr/include/boost/phoenix/operator/arithmetic.hpp:13:0,
 from /usr/include/boost/phoenix/operator.hpp:13, from /usr/include/boost
/phoenix/phoenix.hpp:13, from 1: /usr/include/boost/proto/operators.hpp:295:9:
 note: template<class Left, class Right> const typename 
boost::proto::detail::enable_binary<boost::proto::domainns_::deduce_domain, 
boost::proto::detail::not_a_grammar, 
boost::mpl::or_<boost::proto::is_extension<Arg>, 
boost::proto::is_extension<Right> >, boost::proto::tagns_::tag::mem_ptr, const
 Left&, const Right&>::type boost::proto::exprns_::operator->*(Left&&, 
Right&&) BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS(is_extension, deduce_domain) ^ 
/usr/include/boost/proto/operators.hpp:295:9: note: template argument 
deduction/substitution failed: 17:28: note: couldn't deduce template parameter 
'Right'
```

However, if I comment the line `void func(int id) { m_id = id; }` out, it works as expected.

How can I tell which of the overloads to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling (member) function pointers to overload sets is always a pain. You need to cast the address to a pointer that has the exact signature of the desired overload. In your case, for selection `int A::func()`:

```
auto retVal = (arg1->*static_cast<int (A::*)() const>(&A::func))()(a);
```

or a bit more readable, but basically the same:

```
const auto memFctPtr = static_cast<int (A::*)() const>(&A::func);
auto retVal = (arg1->*memFctPtr)()(a);
```

Comment: You could also wrap the static_cast in a helper function that has the same function signature interface as e.g. `std::function`.